# django registeration verification of email not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, web-deployment, email-verification, django-3.0

I followed blog https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef for email verification but it adding a user before verification of link.

Comment: The user should be created before the verification link, the verification link should just enable/activate the user. You can see in the views code it does `user.is_active = False; user.save()` which creates the user then goes on to do `email.send()` after that

Comment: Well just now i dont see a problem, maybe you should update your question detailing what the issue is? Do you mean to say the user can login before using the link? or do you mean the user cant login even after using the link? whats the actual issue. becuase the user being created before the link is not an issue, thats the expected behaviour

Comment: yes but thats the expected behaviour, the user will get created in the db with active status as false, a verification link will be sent. When verification link is clikced, token will be validated and user active flag will be set to True. So what is the issue. To me it all sounds like its working as it should

Comment: No that happens when the link is followed. look in the views.py `if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token): user.is_active = True; user.save()`

Comment: So again i ask, what is the actual problem yo uare facing

Comment: the user should create if the user verify (click on) .unless account should not create

Comment: No thats not how it works. How would yo ube able to create the user after the link is clicked? the link its self doesnt contain any of the user data. So if the user didnt click the link for 2 days, how would your app meant to remember user data. The idea is that you create the user at the time of registration and you save the user with active flag as false. This will prevent the user being able to login. So they are created but not active. Then when link is clicked, if link is valid and token valid the user active flag will be set to true. Then user will be allowed to login